# CSS: display preview for cropped image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jcrop

I am cropping an image using Jcrop and I am getting the coordinates. I want to display preview for the cropped part upon clicking on "Preview" button. I am not sure how can I achieve that.

Comment: anycode you tried yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it following their [thumbnail example](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail) with some deviations.

```
$(function () {
    var $target = $('#target'),
        $preview = $('#preview');
    // hold the coordinates of the cropped image
    var coords;
    // initialize the widget
    $target.Jcrop({
        // save the coordinates of the cropped image after selecting
        onSelect: function (c) {
           coords = c;
        }
    });
    // when a button is clicked, show preview of the cropped image using the saved coordinates 
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        // make a copy of the image with the original dimensions
        var $img = $('<img/>', {
            src: $target[0].src,
            css: {
              position: 'absolute',
              left: '-' + Math.round(coords.x) + 'px',
              top: '-' + Math.round(coords.y) + 'px',
              width: $target.css('width'),
              height: $target.css('height')
            }
        });
        // set the dimensions of the preview container
        $preview.css({
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: Math.round(coords.w) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(coords.h) + 'px'
        });
        // add+position image relative to its container 
        $preview.html($img);
    });
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/kitewimuvo/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you could crop and save the image after you click the preview button with ajax and load it in a modal or fancybox

Comment: In my case I don't want to save the image unless the preview image is approved by the user. Is there any way?